# scoring in SAS 9.2

Tags: model, sas, glm, scoring

Has someone created manual code to score a dataset using results from proc glm in SAS?

Note: In this study there are two different programs, with 3 versions of two different programs. 
X01
X02
X03
Y01
Y02
Y03

```
proc glm data=maindata;
 class program_group;
 model program_score = prog_group TOBACCO DRUGS ALCOHOL age_on_admit 
                      yrs_in_program stand_test_score
                      / solution ss1 ss3;
      format program_group $program_group.
;
output out = results predicted=phat r=resid;
ods output parameterestimates = out.program_test_year1;
run;
```

Do I need to create dummy variables for the 6 different program groups when I run proc glm if I intend to read in the parameter estimates manually and score another dataset?

Comment: Why? There's PROC SCORE and several other ways...http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2014/02/19/scoring-a-regression-model-in-sas.html

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Since you have SAS 9.2 then you should use PROC SCORE. 
Another trick is to include your data in the model data and leave the y/dependent value blank. If you get an output set of the scored data your additional data will also be scored. You can get this via `OUTPUT out=want p=predicted;`

There's PROC SCORE and several other ways. 
The CODE statement is new and underused - probably what you're looking for.

```
proc glm data=A noprint;
model y = x | x | x;  
code file='glmScore.sas';
quit;

data Pred;
set ScoreX;
%include 'glmScore.sas';
run;
```

See a list of ways itemized here:
http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2014/02/19/scoring-a-regression-model-in-sas.html